# Strange object instantiation

Tags: c++

In Bjarne Stroustrup's book:Tour of C++, I have found following snippet:

```
void test(){
 string input = "aa as; asd ++easdf asdfg";
 regex pat {R"(\s+(\w+))"};
 for (sregex_iterator p(input.begin(),input.end(),pat); p!=sregex_iterator{}; ++p)
  cout << (*p)[1] << '\n';
}
```

I have a problem understanding what is `sregex_iterator{}` doing. What kind of statement is it? Constructor? Initializer List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is creating a (temporary) object of type `std::sregex_iterator` by calling its default constructor (using uniform syntax). Since C++14, the standard requires that all types that model the `ForwardIterator` concept be `DefaultConstructible` and that a default-constructed iterator represents a past-the-end iterator.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator):

> **Singular iterators *(since C++14)***
>
> A value-initialized `ForwardIterator` behaves like the past-the-end iterator of some unspecified empty container: it compares equal to all value-initialized `ForwardIterators` of the same type.

So the complete `p!=sregex_iterator{};` statement checks whether the iterator `p` is not yet exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

It is calling the default constructor using [Uniform Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) introduced in C++11.

Comment: You might want to edit the answer to indicate that Uniform Initialization is a C++11 thing.